# how to display wordpress acf custom fields in front end form posting

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

In my project  I need to display  custom post  fields form  on front end  , so I have installed ACF and created  custom filed , now my issue is how to render these fields along with the  HTML ????   I used get_fields()  function  , still it won't display  any HTML code .

Comment: how did you use get_fields()? show us..

Answer (score 5):

If you want to show the fields inside the post, you have to place the code inside the loop of "single.php", supposing you are using the standard post type.

This code retrive the field only, it won't show anything, it's used to store the value in a variable:

```
get_field('field-name');
```

To make the fields show in the template you have to use the following:

```
the_field('field-name');
```

You can also insert the code in the archive template or query post your are using to show posts.

This also would work:

```
echo get_field('field-name')
```

or

```
$myfield = get_field('field-name');
echo $myfield;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use ACF Frontend display plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-frontend-display

Check "display on front" within post or page editing.

If you want add some actions try to use Forms actions plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/forms-actions/

Answer (score 1):

Add that code no your template :

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Resume Build
 *
 * @package Betheme
 * @author Muffin Group
 */
?>
<?php
/**
 * The main template file.
 *
 * @package Betheme
 * @author Muffin group
 * @link http://muffingroup.com
 */
acf_form_head();
get_header();


?>


<!-- #Content -->
<div id="Content">
    <div class="content_wrapper clearfix">

        <!-- .sections_group -->
        <div class="sections_group">

            <div id="content">

    <?php

    acf_form(array(
        'post_id'       => 'new_post',
        'post_title'    => true,
        'post_content'  => false,
        'new_post'      => array(
            'post_type'     => 'resume',
            'post_status'   => 'publish'
        )
    ));

    ?>

</div>



        </div>  

        <!-- .four-columns - sidebar -->
        <?php get_sidebar( 'blog' ); ?>

    </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer();

// Omit Closing PHP Tags
```

Comment: thanks mate.. was missing that acf_form_head - gr8 help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [Documents](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/create-a-front-end-form/)...

You can add fields or full form with following function,

```
$options = array(
    'post_id' => $post->ID, // post id to get field groups from and save data to
    'field_groups' => array(), // this will find the field groups for this post (post ID's of the acf post objects)
    'form' => true, // set this to false to prevent the <form> tag from being created
    'form_attributes' => array( // attributes will be added to the form element
        'id' => 'post',
        'class' => '',
        'action' => '',
        'method' => 'post',
    ),
    'return' => add_query_arg( 'updated', 'true', get_permalink() ), // return url
    'html_before_fields' => '', // html inside form before fields
    'html_after_fields' => '', // html inside form after fields
    'submit_value' => 'Update', // value for submit field
    'updated_message' => 'Post updated.', // default updated message. Can be false to show no message
);
acf_form( $options );
```

Hope this will help you...

Comment: Hi , Thanks for helping me out  , but this is my requirement  . I created one custom field group.. and  I am allowing users to create posts from FF ,so when when users create new post I want this fields to  be visible to users...

Answer (score 0):

All is explain in [that document](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/create-a-front-end-form/)

Plus, there is a function [here](http://www.telegraphicsinc.com/2013/07/how-to-add-new-post-title-using-aacf_form/) which will help you